# How can I see in SMS app my messages sent from within my app?

Tags: android, sms, android-intent, notify

I have just created a cool app that work with SMS.
You have just to send some SMS to your phone and it reply with location and some handy stuff. Usefull for my frieds, I just told them send me a SMS with "WhereIs" and I will automatically reply you with my position

For the response, I use:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, position, pi, null);
```

And that is very fine.

Unfortunately, all sent SMS does not appear in my SMS application, so I don't know that a SMS has been send.

I really would like to know what the people asking me are receiving as answer.

So, to create a correct question:

Is there a way to "tell" the SMS app that I sent some sms in my application?

Thank a lot for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just an information: You should always use the SMSManager from the "android.telephony"-package, because the one from the "android.telephony.gsm"-package is deprecated.

To your Question: You can check if the message was successfully send by using the "Activity.RESULT_OK"-global in the Activity you specified with the Intent "pi". See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't want to chack if message has been correctly send, I just want to see what was written in the SMS app and read the conversation like I sent a classic SMS.

Comment: To see the Text that was send from your device, you could simply create a Toast showing your 'position'-String. I don't know why the send SMS shouldn't appear in your standard SMS app. You could try completely restarting your Phone to see, if the send message is in the App then. If it's not, i don't know if it's possible...

Comment: Hello Lukas, seem that the answer to my question is "no, that's not possible"? I know a lot of possibilities to see send messages within my app (Toast, like you said, SQL database; etc...), but I would prefer to have everything in SMS app. I therefore "voted" for your help to give you some bonus on StackOverflow, but I prefer to wait for an other answer, even if I strongly believe it will never come...

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add that message to Android's built in "Sent folder" aka "content://sms/sent". I have not tried it but I guess it should work. Cause if I am not wrong all the messages app would get your sent messages from this location. Give it a try. Please check as answer if this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
             values.put("address", incomingNumber); 
              //values.put("date",(String)s); 
              values.put("protocol", "0"); 
              values.put("read", "1"); 
              values.put("status", "-1"); 
              values.put("type", "1"); 
              values.put("body", selectedText);  
              ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
              Uri newUri=contentResolver.insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

but the prblm is tht its showing as the inbox message that is sent by the incomingNumber...not as the sent items....